# How to detect when SELECT * is the same?

Tags: java, python, sql, database

I would like to build a very basic function to see if a query ran at time X has the same result-set structure (ignoring order and data) as a previous query. This has two components:

1. Are the un-ordered select projections the same?

   `SELECT firstname, lastname FROM table`

   Is the same as:

   `SELET lastname, firstname FROM table WHERE date="2014-01-01"`
2. Are `*` projections the same? For example:

   `SELECT * FROM table`

   Ran now, this might not be the same as this same query ran in 15 minutes, once I add two columns to the table.

What might be a good way to resolve to see if the two result-sets are the same without running the entire query? Or, is that even possible?

Perhaps the crudest approach might be to just add a `limit 1` and then check the matching `[Name+Type]`'s.

---

(Tagging with python since that's the language I'm most familiar with, but open to suggestions/answers in any language).

Comment: In your descriptions for the second case, what do you mean by field? Do you mean the columns or records? You want to check only columns structure, right?

Comment: @AliTou yes only columns, the values/data itself I don't care about. I.e., if someone did a `truncate table` that wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: In what language do you propose to build such a function? Standard SQL is not among your options, but it would be possible in various host languages that use embedded SQL.

Comment: @JohnBollinger any language is fine (python, java, etc.). Though it seems on Stackoverflow if I would tag a question like this with `Java` I would get 10 downvotes almost immediately complaining the question isn't specific enough.

Comment: In general you won't know the answer until you run both queries and compare.  The database itself also doesn't always know 100%, as statistics aren't always entirely up to date.

Comment: And I'm afraid that *without* a tag for a host language it's *really* not specific enough.  In many host languages, and in Java in particular, it is possible to extract the *metadata* from a result set, which includes all the column names and types.  If I understand the question then that's the information you need.  But you *do* need to actually execute a query to get it (perhaps with `limit 1`, as you suggest).

Comment: @JohnBollinger yea I think in the odbc connection it should always return the field metadata, something like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldescribecol-function. Sure I'll tag a language.

Comment: Note also that yours is a problem that most programs assume they do not need to address.  It is not ordinarilly a responsibility of the program to make such determinations.

Comment: The crude way is actually to use `limit 0` and just look at the headers.